# Gulp - difference between function done() vs gulp.series

Tags: javascript, gulp, zurb-foundation

I have two questions about [Foundation's gulpfile](https://github.com/zurb/foundation-zurb-template/blob/master/gulpfile.babel.js).

By default `gulp` launches all the tasks at once and waits for nothing. To run tasks in a particular order we need to give a hint to tell gulp when the task is done ([read more](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/API.md#return-a-promise)):

```
function reload(done) {
  browser.reload();
  done();
}
```

**But why since later there's** `gulp.series`:

```
function watch() {
  gulp.watch('src/assets/scss/**/*.scss').on('all', gulp.series(sass,browser.reload));
}
```

My questions are:

1. Why using `function done()` and `gulp.series` simultaneously?
2. What `on('all')` does? I can't find anything in docs about it.

Answer (score 0):

It's all about new Gulp 4. Helpful links:

1. [The Complete-Ish Guide to Upgrading to Gulp 4](https://www.joezimjs.com/javascript/complete-guide-upgrading-gulp-4/)
2. [Gulp 4 docs](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/4.0/docs/API.md)